# Compare same column rows for an ID and reduce the rows into desired output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

| Student ID | Subject | SID | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | English | 1 | Pass |
| 101 | English | 1 | Pass |
| 101 | Mathematics | 3 | Pass |
| 101 | Mathematics | 3 | Pass |
| 101 | Mathematics | 33 | Fail |
| 101 | Mathematics | 33 | Fail |
| 102 | English | 1 | Pass |
| 102 | English | 1 | Pass |
| 102 | Mathematics | 3 | Fail |
| 102 | Mathematics | 3 | Fail |

I want an output like this

| Subject | SID | Pass | Fail | Failed_student_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| English | 1 | 2 | 0 |  |
| Mathematics | 3 | 1 | 1 | 102 |
| Mathematics | 33 | 0 | 1 | 101 |

I have a large dataset and want to take the result with respect to subject and subject ID on how many people passed and failed.

How do I write in python to get this kind of data frame?

Comment: Are there always duplicated rows?

Comment: Yes, the number of duplicated rows shows the number questions present for the SID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with aggfunc of `len` to get count of `Pass`, `Fail` and `reset_index`

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)
df = (df.drop('Student ID', axis=1).
    pivot_table(index=['Subject', 'SID'],
               columns='Result',
               aggfunc=len,
               fill_value=0).
    rename_axis('', axis=1).
    reset_index()
     )
df['Total Students'] = df['Pass'] + df['Fail']
```

print(df):

```
       Subject  SID  Fail  Pass  Total Students
0      English    1     0     2               2
1  Mathematics    3     1     1               2
2  Mathematics   33     1     0               1
```

**Failed Student ID**:

If you need Failed Student ID, you need to do more - include 'Student ID' in the pivot_table with `list` aggfunc and do some rearranging of columns:

```
df = (df.
    pivot_table(index=['Subject', 'SID'],
               columns=['Result'],
               values=['Student ID'],
               aggfunc={'Result':len,'Student ID':list},
               fill_value=0)
     )
df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index()
df = df.drop(('Student ID', 'Pass'),axis=1)
df.columns = ['Fail', 'Pass', 'Failed_Student_ID']
df = df.reset_index()
```

print(df):

```
       Subject  SID  Fail  Pass Failed_Student_ID
0      English    1     0     2                 0
1  Mathematics    3     1     1             [102]
2  Mathematics   33     1     0             [101]
```

Comment: Hi, I have revised my question. the above code works fine. thank you. Can you give a solution for this "instead of total students if I want the students id failed", how should I proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function get_dummies and group by the columns "Student ID" and "Subject", something like this:

```
marks = pd.DataFrame({
    'student':   ['100','100', '101'],
    'subject': ['math', 'math', 'math'],
    'result': ['pass', 'pass', 'failed']
})
marks[['failed','pass']] = pd.get_dummies(marks.result)
marks.groupby(['student','subject']).sum()
```

Comment: typo, corrected

Answer (score 1):

You can drop all the duplicates in your dataframe, then using groupby to count the values of the Pass and Fail in every subject.

```
result = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['Subject','SID'])['Result'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()

Result      Subject  SID  Fail  Pass
0           English    1     0     2
1       Mathematics    3     1     1
2       Mathematics   33     1     0

result['Total student'] = result[['Fail','Pass']].sum(axis=1)
```